# Visual Studio 2012 - access file in different directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I know there are many topics similar to this, but I've been unable to find a solution after looking through dozens of results.

I have a Project "Foo", and my controller is at "Foo\Controllers\Bar.cs, and in that C# file, I want to read from a file, located at "Foo\Data\Stuff.txt". It's so simple, but nothing I've tried works, mainly because things like `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and all similar built-in functions reference the executing directory (in my case, "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express").

What am I doing wrong? Or if I missed an identical question, please direct me there, this seems to small an issue to have spent so much time on. Thanks!

Comment: try using [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That was definitely the easiest, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With command Server.MapPath("Foo\Data\Stuff.txt") you will find the phisical path where the file is stored

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`, which allows you to find exactly where your running .exe is located; regardless of whether you're in the debugger or not.

Here's an example that uses "CodeBase" to find the path, then reads the Windows version info from the .exe:

```
// GetWindowsVersion: Fetch Winver info from specified file
public static string GetWindowsFileVersion()
{
    String codeBaseUri =
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    String codeBase =
        new Uri(codeBaseUri).LocalPath;
    System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(codeBase);
    return info.FileVersion.ToString();
}
```